# Accessing the Internet via browser

Tags: windows-7, internet, virus

I am on Windows 7 and using Firefox browser. I am using WiFi, but since the morning I cannot access the Internet via the browsers (Firefox, Chrome, or IE). The laptop shows there is Internet connection, Skype is online, but I can't reach the Internet. Then I launched Tor application which creates secure channel and provides its Firefox browser. Well, I can now access the Internet over that browser. 
So, what might be the problem causing this malfunction?

The error:

```
      The connection has timed out                 

      The server at mail.google.com is taking too long to respond.     

  The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
    moments.
  If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
  If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Best regards

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem. You say you "cannot access the Internet". Well, what happens when you try? How far do you get? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a proxy issue then. Check your local proxy settings via firefox options  -> choose the advanced tab -> select network -> choose settings under the network section and check your manual configuration.

Is it set to auto? Or does it have an entry in there under manual proxy config? Such as Tor proxy settings when Tor isnt running?

Comment: 'No proxy' has been selected.

Comment: what happens when you try and ping google.com from command line?

Comment: The 'ping' works fine. It returns results.

Comment: how about viewing your hosts file, see if there are any references to 127.0.0.1 that might be killing your routes.